# The incarnations of Lord Vamana and Lord Parushurama

Tags: vishnu, vamana

Here's the plot, according to Hindu mythology and the dashavatharas, chronologically, Lord Vamana incarnated before Lord Parushurama. According to the popular folklore and existing beliefs in Kerala, King Mahabali was said to have to have ruled over the land now called Kerala. He is still remembered as one of the greatest rulers who have ever taken throne. Therefore, he's still remembered during the festival of "Onam". And it is said that Lord Vamana was the one who sentenced Mahabali to his eternal exile. 
 But, it is also said that Lord Parusharama is the one who forged the Land of Kerala from his mighty axe. According to Dahshavaratha, chronologically, Lord Vishnu is said to have taken the form of Lord Vamana before that of Lord Parushurama. How?

Comment: Parashurama didn't create new land out of thin air, he reclaimed land that had formerly been under the sea.  So I think the explanation is simply that the land that is now Kerala was submerged after the time of Mahabali, and then Parashurama reclaimed it from the sea.

Comment: Onam is mostly related to agriculture and the importance is given to vamana. The kingdom of Mahabali should have been in the north-eastern part of India. The baghavatha says he did yaga on the banks of Narmada river which is too far from Kerala. Anyway for confirming any of this claims more references are needed.